# Ignore source control of added third-party frameworks etc

Tags: xcode, version-control

My project is git version control enabled. I have a problem if I add something from cloned third-party repository.

The problem is that files have their repositories and they appears in Source Control -> Working Copies and make some problems.

Can I have them added to project from some local cloned git-repository and ignore their repositories without making copy of those files?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use git submodules.  This basically stores a *reference* to the dependency's git repo and the commit you have decided to use of that dependency, within your own git repo.

It does not store the dependency's git repo as a whole and means you can easily choose to use an earlier commit than `HEAD` of that dependent repo.

[Reference](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) (many others available on the internet).

Comment: Can I add files references from third-party repository without init their repositories like submodules?

If I add just one class from third-party repo I have whole repo included to my project (showing in Working Copies) and this thing annoying me.

I don't want to use submodules. I wan't to add files from third-party local repo like a non version control enabled files, like a normal files from any local storage.

Comment: @Jauzee Well you can just copy those files from their repos, however they become uncontrolled and unmaintained.

Answer (score 0):

[trojanfoe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33925278/255489) is definitely the way to go for straight repos, but if the projects are available via [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org) or [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage), I'd recommend doing that instead of using submodules.